# Associate buttons and click actions in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mutable

I am trying to associate several click actions to several buttons, in jQuery. I am using a for loop to browse all the buttons.

I tried something like that :

```
var realThis = $(this);

// ...

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(buttons[i].callback) !== 'undefined')
        $('#' + buttons[i].id).click(function(){ 
            buttons[i].callback(realThis.getFormValues()); 
        });
}
```

I got a warning from my editing software :

> Mutable variable is accessible from closure

I tried several things without any success.

Any help here ?

Comment: Your code here seems a little over-complicated. If all the buttons have the same event handler you don't need to assign it in a loop. You can use a class to select all the elements at once.

Comment: Did you try to set `var formValues = realThis.getFormValues();` before loop and inside use `buttons[i].callback(formValues); `?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, for your answer. All the callback functions could be different from a button to an other :/ I can't avoid the use of a loop.

Comment: @dfsq I think this behavior would not suit what I need. Indeed, I want to pass the result of `realThis.getFormValues()` only when the button is clicked. The result of `realThis.getFormValues()` could change any time.

Comment: I tried :

 `for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  if(typeof(buttons[i].callback) !== 'undefined') {
   var t = buttons[i].callback;

   $('#' + buttons[i].id).click(function() {
    t(realThis.getFormValues());
   });
  }
 }`

But it is not working either. When I click one of the buttons, the callback function called is always the one of the last iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @fef what about the definition of callback function. What is going  to be performed when callback() function is invoked? do you want to create dynamic functions for each button?

Comment: @TintuCRaju Technically, the function can be everything since its a parameter of my plugin. The user can pass any function he wants, and use the results of `.getFormValues()` as he wants.

Here is a technical example :
`'buttons':
[
 {
  'name': 'Validate',
  'id': 'validate',
  'activation': true,
  'callback': function(formValues){ console.log('one: ', formValues)}
 },
 {
  'name': 'Reset',
  'id': 'reset',
  'activation': true,
  'callback': function(formValues){ console.log('two: ', formValues)}
 }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to my problem :

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    (function()
    {
        if(buttons[i].callback)
        {
            var callbackTemp = buttons[i].callback;

            $('#' + buttons[i].id).click(function(){ callbackTemp(realThis.getFormValues()); });
        }
    })();
}
```

Thanks for you help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the structure of your HTML so that you know which handler will be attached. Data attributes might help you:

```
<button id="button-1" data-button-id="1" class="button-action">
  Do action 1
</button>

<button id="button-2" data-button-id="2" class="button-action">
  Do action 2
</button>
```

You can then attach your handlers to all buttons, and work out which function you want to call on click, instead of in advance:

```
$('.button-action').on('click', function (e) {
   // get the button index from the data attribute
   var buttonId = $(e.currentTarget).data('buttonId');
   // if there's a callback then execute it
   if (buttons[buttonId].callback) {   
     buttons[buttonId].callback(realThis.getFormValues());
   }
});
```